# Best way to remove duplicated columns in linux

Tags: bash, shell, command, uniq

It should be like running uniq command, but by columns. For example:

A B C B
A C B C
A A A A

Second and fourth columns are identical. Which is the best way to obtain the following result?

A B C
A C B
A A A

However, at first it is unknown which columns are identical, much like with the uniq command for rows.

Comment: If the columns are meant to be uniq then shouldn't the last column be "A" and not "A A A"?

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lane '
    push @{ $c[$_] }, $F[$_] for 0 .. $#F;
    }{
    for (@c) {
        $s = join "|", @$_;
        $seen{$s}++ or push @r, $_;
    }
    print join " ", map shift @$_, @r while @{ $r[0] }
    ' -- inputfile
```

The first line pivots the input, i.e. it creates the following structure:

```
@c = ( [ 'A', 'A', 'A' ],
       [ 'B', 'C', 'A' ],
       [ 'C', 'B', 'A' ],
       [ 'B', 'C', 'A' ] );
```

The `}{` (called "Eskimo greeting") separates the code run for each line from the code run after the whole input has been processed. It walks the @c array and only keeps the unique columns (by creating a string from each of them like `A|A|A`, `B|C|A`, etc. and storing them in the `%seen` hash.

The structure will be

```
@r = ( [ 'A', 'A', 'A' ],
       [ 'B', 'C', 'A' ],
       [ 'C', 'B', 'A' ] );
```

and the hash will look like

```
%seen = ( 'B|C|A' => 2,
          'A|A|A' => 1,
          'C|B|A' => 1
);
```

The last print shifts the first element of each column, i.e. it pivots the result back.